# What is this object?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I know this is a data object but I'm new to python and I don't understand what user_output is doing. Trying to understand all this.

```
def user_output(self,check): #data object 
    output = ""
    #loop of all the info for __user_arr
    for user in self.__user_arr:
        if user.user_bot == str(check):
            output += '''
    <div class='about'>
        <h1>{user.user_name}</h1>
        <h2>My favorite band is: {user.user_band} </h2>
        <div class='business'>
            <p>Why I want the tickets:<br /> {user.user_business}</p>
        </div>
    </div>
            '''
            return output.format(**locals())
        else: #this will spit an error if the user do not answer the last question correctly.
            output = '''<div class='error'><h2>Turns out you are a robot. No tickets for you </h2></div>'''
            return output
```

Comment: In the future, please read [this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253894/how-to-handle-explain-how-this-code-dump-works-questions) before asking code dump questions again.

Comment: Sorry Matt my mistake.

Answer (score 0):

It will generate for each user a `div` block with some favorite bands etc. , provided that, the user flag `user_bot` is equal to `check` (as far as I can understand a kind of bot check). If the user is a bot (does not pass the check) the program will generate the `Turns out you are a robot..` block.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a function, not an object. It checks whether your user is a robot. It does so by checking if your user (for every user) has their `user_bot` as the string you get as input, probably a string identifying robots. Then you write something I know nothing about to the output string, probably selling the ticket.
This function seems to do this only for the first user, though because it returns in the first `if else` clause.

Answer (score 0):

`user_output()` seems to be a method in some class. It is using a "poor man's" tempting facility to output an HTML fragment.

It appears to use a loop, `for user in self.__user_arr:`, but this is a bit of a sham. It uses this construct to pick the first item out of `self.__user_arr`. Because it soon returns from the function under all conditions, it will never return to the head of the loop to check subsequent users (if any).

Also note that the double-understore prefix to `self.__user_arr` marks it as a private part of the implementation of the object. A deeply private part. A single underscore usually indicates "private." Double underscores don't have a super-precise definition, but "very private" or "very implementation dependent" would be my guess.

If the `user_bot` property of that first user is a string equal to the `check` value (as stringified), then the template is instantiated. It does this first by setting a string variable (`output`) which has embedded in tt the variable markers (`{a_variable}`) compatible with `str`'s `format` method. Calling `output.format(**locals())` does the string formatting operation using `locals()` (which is a lookup dictionary of all current variable assignments, a.k.a. a symbol table). The `**locals()` construction means "use this dict (or dict-like) object as though it were a set of keyword arguments." The effect is that substrings in `output` like `{user.user_band}` are directly interpolated into the `output` string. Then the filled-in string is returned.

If, instead, the `user.user_bot == str(check)` test fails, a simple error string is returned.

In either case, a string is returned, and the method exits.

The only other case worth considering is what if there are no users in the `self.__user_arr` collection? Then the loop would never run, and the method would return `None` implicitly.